# Android manifest pathAdvancedPattern with optional words, is it possible?

Tags: android, regex, react-native, mobile, deep-linking

So I am trying to implement app links from web search to open the app and I want it to use regex to match the below URL example...

`/(url-1|url-2)/`

Where it can be either of those strings, but it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible in the pattern matcher?

Anywhere exists a tool to test this, can't seem to find any other than generic regex testers which are different to the android format here.

Comment: [This resource](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-handle-deep-link-with-complex-path-like-this-811216a0c802) claims there is no `(...|...)` support in `pathAdvancedPattern`.

Comment: interesting, thanks. So I assume I will have to create many intents with different paths to get what I need, which is essentially dynamic url matching?